# How to create/split multiple frame TIFF image using Python PIL or Pillow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

PIL has seek(frame) function to seek through multi frame file and tell() function to return the current frame number.
Is it possible to create such multiple frame TIFF image using PIL or Pillow (or using any other library)?

Answer (score 0):

scikit-image and numpy packages can be used.
For example:

```
import from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from numpy import *

im = imread("fileName.tiff")
im_array = array_split(im, 2, axis=3) # dividing the array into 2 parts along the 3rd axis
imsave("part1.tiff", im_array[0])
imsave("part2.tiff", im_array[1])
```